# Is there a way to get the compression benefits of JPEG but with transparent pixels?

Tags: ios, compression, jpeg, image-compression

I have an iOS app that displays lots of thumbnails on the screen. It's a requirement that the thumbnails have a transparent background.

I store these images as PNG's so that I can get transparency, but all of the images are photographs, so JPEG compression would be perfect for this use case.

In testing, using JPEG's instead of PNG's cuts my disk usage by 90% on average and would reduce needless disk I/O. Unfortunately, I can't make the switch because I would lose the transparency information.

Is there a variant of JPEG (ideally, something that works with the iOS SDK) that allows me to compress photographic images but still keep transparent pixels? I don't actually need a full alpha channel - I just need some pixels to be fully transparent and some to be fully opaque.

Comment: Do you need the same area to be transparent? Such as showing the images cropped to a circle shape? Or are the transparent areas unique for every image?

Comment: @DonMag No, that would be nice though! :) The transparent regions are arbitrary.

Comment: You can try using https://tinypng.com ... quick test *appears* to work... reduced my test `312x324` photo png from `133,099` bytes to `40,244` while keeping transparency. Loaded into a `UIImageView` without problem.

Comment: @DonMag This is something that will have to be done in the app, to user-provided images - rather than something I'm shipping as a resource

Comment: Well, they have a dev API ... your app would have to send the image and then save the returned, compressed image locally. Another option would be to write your own "smart lossy compression" algorithm :)

Comment: You could save two jpegs. One being the opaque image and the other the alpha channel, then combine them once they have loaded.

Comment: I have created an iOS framework that uses colortable table lookup for alpha channel + near lossless results, see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031398/763355

Answer (score 0):

I am told that it is possible to use a JPEG with a transparency mask using SVG. I also understand there is 3d party code to display SVG files in IOS.